# AR Studio scripting questions

Tags: facebook, augmented-reality

I am starting dip my toes in Facebook AR Studio and even knowing JS it's very confusing to debug and testing some methods...
example:
THIS WORKS:

```
Diagnostics.log(FaceTracking.face(0).mouth.openness.lastValue);
```

and if I do this:

```
Diagnostics.log(FaceTracking.face(0).mouth.openness);
```

it's showed in the console.log all the options of the class.

OK! But when I do the same thing, but with another class, like "eye", an error occurs:

```
Diagnostics.log(FaceTracking.face(0).eye.openness);
```

or:

```
Diagnostics.log(FaceTracking.face(0).eyebrow.top);
JavaScript error: TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'FaceTracking.face(0).eyebrow.top')
```

I tried with eyebrow and eye and nothing happens, just the error message.
What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is "eye" is not a property of FaceTracking.
You must specify which eye you want to monitor "leftEye" or "rightEye".
Try to log just the face method like this:

```
Diagnostics.log(FaceTracking.face(0))
```

You can see in the console all of the methods and properties available, like leftEye, rightEye, leftEyebrow, rightEyebrow, mouth, etc. You can go deeper logging each one of those like:

```
Diagnostics.log(FaceTracking.face(0).rightEye)
```

And then see for yourself the features "rightEye" provides.

I strongly recommend you to use Diagnostics to understand which methods and properties are available for the Modules you're working with. You can pretty much log everything inside the SDK. I even wrote an entire tutorial about it on Medium ;)

Comment: hey trinca! can you send the medium article?

Comment: Here it goes: https://medium.com/@marcostrinca/facebook-camera-effects-tutorials-part-1-9ccadcffc4d7

Answer (score 1):

As Trinca mentioned, "eye" is not a valid property of the Face module. You can see a list of valid properties on the documentation page here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/camera-effects/reference/facetracking_module/face_class

And the available properties of the Eye module can be found here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/camera-effects/reference/facetracking_module/eye_class

For your purposed this should work:

```
Diagnostics.watch("left eye openness", FaceTracking.face(0).leftEye.openness);
Diagnostics.watch("right eye openness", FaceTracking.face(0).rightEye.openness);
```